# styled-components Toggle-Restart animation

Tags: css, reactjs, redux, react-redux, styled-components

I have a magnifier glass icon, that I'd like to wiggle with a css one time animation. However it only works the first time.

```
const IconSearch = styled.span`
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  perspective: 1000px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  color: ${({ theme }) => theme.color.sidebar.search.box.icon};
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 48px;
  font-family: "${({ theme }) => theme.font.icon}";
  font-weight: 700;
  &::before {
    content: "\f002";
  }
  &.a {
    animation: wiggle 0.85s cubic-bezier(0.36, 0.07, 0.19, 0.97) both;
  }
`;
```

It is initiated when `this.props.wiggle` is `true`.

```
<IconSearch className={!this.props.wiggle ? "" : "a"}></IconSearch>
```

The way I am trying to toggle it is like this (Redux Slice reducer):

```
searchWiggle: (search) => {
  if (search.wiggle) {
    search.wiggle = false;
    search.wiggle = true;
  } else {
    search.wiggle = true;
  }
},
```

However the state is updated too fast, and the animation does not run after the very first time.

How can I reset the animation, so that it runs every time `search.wiggle` is updated?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `key` prop (that tells React to rerender the component) set with search.wiggle value. ([Cf similar issue here](https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/jzl4q1/how_to_trigger_again_a_keyframe_animation_with/))